# How to deploy a Web Service from Xamarin Studio

Tags: asp.net, web-services, xamarin-studio

Good afternoon, everyone.

I'm running Xamarin Studio (Mac OS) and I need to deploy a Web Service in order to build a safe communication with a MySql Database which my Xamarin.Forms app depends on

So far I've opened a new solution and added a new "Web Service with CodeBehind" from the ASP.NET Web Forms palette.
Now I have all template stuff: a DataWebService.asmx with a single line and a DataWebService.asmx.cs with an empty class inheriting from System.Web.Services.WebService.

Now, all I want is to learn how to deploy this Web Service so it can be imported by my other App and consumed.
(I do have a domain to deploy it to, but I won't mind localhost)
In order to make things as simple as possible, a HelloWorld application will do just fine.

----- Extra comments:

I suppose this is pretty much everything I'd have to do in Visual Studio, but I'm avoiding the need of another machine - even a virtual one, once I don't have a Windows license.
It seems to me that a wizard should be able to do the rest, but apparently there isn't such a thing in Xamarin Studio (which I'm hoping to be wrong)
The CodeBehindService.asmx.cs lacks the [WebService] directive I've seen on my research so far, which makes me think Xamarin Studio is still incomplete and can't support me in this task

I don't mind doing some work myself, though I'm not sure of what would be needed. My priority is: deploy

What I have: an almost empty asmx file; a dll binary
What do I do with it?

I tried simply uploading them but the "Add Web Reference" wizard asked for a discovery file; as you can see I lack the basics.

Comment: `[WebMethod]` has little to do with Xamarin Studio. Xamarin Studio is the IDE, not the framework. Anyways, you don't need to do ASMX. Why not make a [console app with Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api), or [Nancy](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Introduction) or [ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api) etc?

Comment: hey mason. I'm aware that Xamarin Studio is the IDE; my question is how to deploy from it; if it can be of any help or what I would need to do in order to do it myself. Thank you for the suggestions, I'll look into it.